# Serverless Lambda Proxy Integration using request validation model - how to get detailed validation error response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm validating the payload of a request via a model - see serverless.yml extract below:

```
functions:
  authorizer:
    handler: src/authorization/authorizer.general
  activity:
    handler: src/resources/activity.submit
    events:
    - http:
        path: /tenant/{tenant}/activities
        method: POST
        cors: true
        authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer.general}
        request:
          schema:
            application/json: ${file(models/activity.json)
```

All works as expected, but the validation response for a payload that does not match the schema is:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid request body"
}
```

I've tried adding a response template but get a warning that 'response' will be removed (this is a lambda proxy integration, not a lambda integration).

How do I get API Gateway to give a detailed validation error message response in this scenario (i.e. a Lambda Proxy integration)?

Any help would be much appreciated as I can't find anything relevant online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this by adding a Gateway Response to override the default Bad Request Body response. Unfortunately, as of Serverless 1.50.0 this is not directly supported (see [github issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3896)

But was able to add the Gateway Response via a Serverless resource i.e. Cloudformation (see above link):

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}
    GatewayResponseResourceNotFound:
      Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
      Properties:
        RestApiId:
          Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
        ResponseType: BAD_REQUEST_BODY
        "StatusCode" : "422"
        ResponseTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"message\": \"$context.error.message\", \"error\": \"$context.error.validationErrorString\"}"
```

Note: I was not able to find a way to indicate which property failed validation, but at least the validation message is a little more detailed